# Bootstrap 4 card grid with 1 large card alignment issues

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gridview, bootstrap-4

My code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row row-cols-xl-3 row-cols-lg-3 row-cols-md-2 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-1">
        <div class="col col-xl-8 col-lg-8">
            <div class="card border-0">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col item">
            <div class="card border-0">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col item">
            <div class="card border-0">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col item">
            <div class="card border-0">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col item">
            <div class="card border-0">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col item">
            <div class="card border-0">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

What I got is this:
[image]

-

I would like to make it look like this:
[image]

How can I do the above with Bootstrap 4?
I cannot get to align the 3rd card under the 2nd card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create 2 colums on the first row then on the second columns (right one) create 2 rows and i think that will work just fine

Comment: Great idea.
It works while on xl and lg screens when I show 3 card per row.
On xs screens it is also ok since I only show 1 card per row.
However, when on md and sm screens I show 2 cards per row, and this solution does not work. :(

Comment: you can specify the number of rows you want on md! just use col-md-x
on col md you might want to use col-md-6 so that every card ocupies half! i think its better than 3!

Comment: Maybe if I show 1 large on first row row and 2 small ones on another row for md and sm screens.

Comment: Yeah you can try that! Or you cant even try to use javascript to detect the size of screen and if is md or sm hide the normal section and show the new one! but that is a little harder